# How to add search to my static laravel site?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm building my first ever website using laravel 5.2. Right now, I'm only serving static content with a few API requests for things like the current weather. I've never built a website before, but I'm running my own droplet at DO, so there's no shared hosting limitations.

How would I implement a search that allows users to search my site's content from the main screen? Currently there's no interaction on a DB, it's all just Blade/HTML. I want to avoid using Google Custom Search as there should be no ads, and I want to learn along the way.

Please advise.

Comment: Just a side Note, if you are builing website why Dont you use a regular cms like word press, and why would you use Laravel with out using database

Comment: With no database, what is it that you are trying to search for? Something similar to control/command + f ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you basically want to create a search that will, in essence, search all of your blade files for specific key-words, and return an array with all the pages containing these key-words. Right?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ because I'm trying to learn and build this by myself at every stage.

Comment: @TheodoreMessinezis - spot on. Eventually I'll be pulling content from the DB, but for the time being the primary information the site will serve is suited to being static. I'd like for potential users (before I rewrite this in a few months to be dynamic) to be able to use a search field to find which view needs to be loaded.

Comment: @Birdman - more or less, but across all of the site's pages. I guess I'm looking for a way to build an index of all content in my blade files and allow users to search that index.

Comment: In my opinion, the benefit from creating such a search does not even begin to compare to the cost. Just moving everything to a database would be much easier...

What about using something like this? https://github.com/mmanos/laravel-search

Comment: Building index means building the `sitemap` kind of thing. It would be a lot nicer and you can submit this same `sitemap` to google for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on the amount of static contents you have in your site. Maybe you could try implementing it the following way.

1. Create lookup of the views pages with the most relevant keywords
2. When user search for keyword which match to any of my relevant keywords, I would load the respective view page.
3. I would store the the lookup in `json` format. It would be similar to contents with multiple tags on them.

Here, creating `json` file is going to be tedious and needs to be done manually.